# How to connect to SQL Server from RStudio server in debian?

Tags: r, kerberos

I am trying to create a ODBC connection to a SQL server instance from my RStudio server on Debian 9.

As the username i have to access the DB is registered under a windows domain, i went through the kerberos installation process. I already installed and configured Kerberos client and its working ok. After running `kinit` i get no output:

```
admonda@campbell:/etc$ kinit -f username
Password for username@YYYYY.NET:
admonda@campbell:/etc$
```

Going back to R, when trying to create the connection, i get a kerberos error. I think im half way but missing something

```
library(RODBC)
library(odbc)
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                 Driver = "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
                 server = "172.30.19.66\\mydb", # remember \\ if your path has a \
                 database = "mydb1",
                 uid = "YYYYY\\username",
                 pwd = "mypassword",
                 Trusted_Connection= "Yes" )
```

_

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SSPI Provider: Server not found in Kerberos database  [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Cannot generate SSPI context
```

Comment: are you sure you need `\\mydb` in server address as you specify `database` argument the line after

Comment: yes. the path needs to be like that in order for the connection to work. if i use a regular non-kerberos user, it will connect